# Using session superglobal (PHP) to check if a user has already registered

Tags: php, html

I wrote a piece of code in PHP to try to implement a session superglobal to check if an user has already registered through a very basic form (only username and email to provide). But when I open my code in my browser through localhost, it only displays a blank page...and I don't know why. 
Thanks a lot for your answers.

Btw...I'm a beginner :)!

NB: in my original .php file I put the doctype, html, head and body tags because of the form in html. I don't know if I have to put it or if it can be automatically recognized as being html. I'm all ear if you can explain :).

NB2: the file was name SESSION.php

Cheers

```
<?php
//Initiate session data
session_start();

//If the user is already registered, display a message letting him know
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    echo "You are already registered as $_SESSION[username].";
}

//Check if the form was submitted
else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //If both fields filled out, store the var in the session var
    //Trim() is used to eliminate leading and trailing whitespace
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['username'])))
        && (!empty(trim($_POST['email']))) {
        //Store espaced $_POST values in variables
            $uname=htmlentities($_POST['username']);
            $email=htmlentities($_POST['email']);

            $_SESSION['username']=$uname;

            echo "Thanks for registering! <br/>",
            "Username: $uname <br/>",
            "Email: $email <br/>";
        }
    //If the user didn't fill out both fields, let him know too
        else {
            echo "Please fill out both fields. <br/>";
        }
    }
//If the form was not submitted at all
    else { ?>
        <form action="SESSION.php?username=overwritten" method="post"> 
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
            <input type="submit" value="Register!" /> 
        </form>
        <?php 
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons depending on the context. Here are a couple of possibilities

1. `session_start()` must always come before any output starts. DOCTYPE, html code, echo/print statements are output among many other possibilities. So it might be failing to start the session properly.
2. check that you have `error_reporting=E_ALL` and `display_errors=1` in your `php.ini` file (it they are not, add/change them and remember to restart webserver afterwards) - this should output rather than hide any errors that you may have. Alternatively check your webserver's (e.g. apache's) error log for details what fails and debug from there

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know what a php.ini file is, so I guess I'll look into that in a close future. And I tried another file without the doctype and other outputs by starting directly with <?php session_start(), but I don't know if I can put the html form is the php file since there will be no doctype set before.

Comment: Btw. if you know any book that is a good resource for PHP beginners (like very beginners), I'll be glad to have the name of it. Cheers.

Comment: Ok I managed to modify the php.ini file and turn `display_errors=On`and apparently it's not an issue with the `session_start()`but with line 26: "unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND)". Since you can't see the lines, it matches: `&& (!empty(trim($_POST['email']))) {`under the comment "//Check if the form was submitted".

Answer (score 0):

First, use

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'On' ); 
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

To display errors in beginning your file

Second, don't use `empty()` function in if statement

Third, you have so many `(` and `)` in your if statement

Try this

```
if(!is_null(trim($_POST['username'])) && (!is_null(trim($_POST['email']))))
```

Comment: 1. There is nothing wrong with `empty()` being in the `if` statement
2. Your way is wrong in the way that a) if `$POST['username']` is not set, you will get a warning when trying to `trim()` it - this is an issue in the original question too; b) `trim()` will always return a string (empty string if it happens so), and any string will never return true for `is_null()`, because `NULL !== ''`

Comment: Idziak, I actually followed a tutorial for that, so I don't get why it doesn't work. I'm not very familiar with all the functions for the time being. But I'm gonna put the errors display command in my code to check if it displays something. Thanks a lot.